# Questions about understanding a template of using bash's getopts

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

[A stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008125/shell-script-common-template) has a template for handling command line arguments.

Does the test `[ $# == 0 ]` mean that a bash script shouldn't be run without any argument? As a template, I think that scripts generally do not  necessarily require  any argument.

In the `case` statement, how different are the two cases `*)` and `"?")` ? They seem the same.

```
# --- Options processing -------------------------------------------
if [ $# == 0 ] ; then
    echo $USAGE
    exit 1;
fi

while getopts ":i:vh" optname
  do
    case "$optname" in
      "v")
        echo "Version $VERSION"
        exit 0;
        ;;
      "i")
        echo "-i argument: $OPTARG"
        ;;
      "h")
        echo $USAGE
        exit 0;
        ;;
      "?")
        echo "Unknown option $OPTARG"
        exit 0;
        ;;
      ":")
        echo "No argument value for option $OPTARG"
        exit 0;
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Unknown error while processing options"
        exit 0;
        ;;
    esac
  done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

param1=$1
param2=$2
```

Comment: There are two questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script requires at least one arg, if not it displays usage info. It should do `echo $USAGE >&2` as this is an error. Other scripts may work with zero arguments, so you will have to modify. Just as some don't take the argument `i`.

## "?", vs *

Yes they are different:

- `"?"` says to case to look for a `?`. This is what getopts returns when it finds an option that it does not expect (invalid option).
- `*` says to case, do this is you find no other match. This should not happen, but it may. It probably indicates a bug in getopts, or more likely your program (see defensive programming).

Answer (score 2):

They should be the same.

However that code has its own share of problems:

- failure to quote arithmetic expansions; should be `shift "$(($OPTIND - 1))"`
- usage of the unportable `==` operator
- error messages written to stdout
- exit with 0 (success) status in case of error
- failure to quote variables; should be `"$#"` and `echo "$USAGE"`
- bad placement of the if-no-arguments check; it should be *after* the getopts loop, in order to not be fooled by `script --`
- useless quoting of `v`, `h`, `i` and `:i:vh`